# What is the most cost effective way to grow a fairy?

Tags: black-desert-online

In Black Desert you can collect items to get a fairy pet that helps you out in various ways. It has different tier levels and levels up to get new skills based on its tier.

There are 2 ways to get a fairy with a new tier. Use the Growth Feature, or dismiss her and get a new fairy.

In order to use growth, the fairy must be at lvl 10 or higher. In order to level her up, you must feed her equipment at green rarity or higher.

So my question is this. What is the most cost effective piece of equipment to level the fairy up? Or is it just not worth it at all and I should just focus on rolling new ones and hope for a higher starting tier.

By cost effective I mean most exp for least cost/effort to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing with the system for a while, There are 2 main ways to grow fairies, both of them centered around **Sweet Honey Wine**. feeding them gear gives far too little exp to be even remotely cost effective. Do not bother with doing Tier Up attempts. Just roll new fairies until you get one you are pleased with.

First Method(and what I've been doing, for now): Sacrifice other fairies. Once you get a Fairy with a tier and personality you are happy with (Brilliant or Radiant tier, personality is personal choice). You can still continue to turn in fairy petals to get more fairies. These fairies can be exchanged for Sweet Honey Wine. Fairy Petals are a rare drop from nearly any activity in the game, and 2 gets you a fairy. It's pretty luck dependent, but I've been able to get 3 fairies in one day, which turned into 5 wine.

Second Method: This is a tougher way of getting Sweet Honey Wine, but it can potentially get you a lot more, and it isn't as reliant on luck (but it still is). The only real requirement, is at least Artisan Rank on Processing... you may be able to get by with Professional, but it will get you a lot of waste:

1. Equip a Hunting Matchlock (any will do, but the stronger the better)
2. Go to *Balenos Forest*, the actual forest part.
3. Start shooting down beehives and gather the honey combs. you're going to need a lot of them 500-1k is a good size batch.
4. Grind the Honeycombs to get **Top Quality Cooking Honey**. The chance of this is pretty low, but Artisan processing has a better chance than finding wild petals... and getting processing to up to that level is pretty easy.
5. Go to your house with a cooking tool and cook:

   - 2 Top-Quality Cooking Honey
   - 4 Full-bodied Exotic Herbal Wine
   - 10 Sugar
   - 2 Fruits

That will get you one Sweet Honey Wine.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until you get a fairy that can learn 4 skills (Keep in mind one will always roll luck when you get the fairy) and then just buy whatever the cheapest green gear is out of the marketplace, with the current event special deals may also be cheaper but it varies from day to day.